# Вертикальный bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, bootstrap

Как я могу сделать еще один `navbar`, чтобы он был вертикальным и прижат четко на одном месте слева?

Как мне в этот `navbar` вставить фоновое изображение для всего столбика или для начала столбика? (Там будет картинка стружки)

Цвет и толщину для него задам сам.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.navbar-collapse {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #993333 0%, #FF6633 100%);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #f3f3f3;
  padding: 4px 68px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  font-weight: bold;
}
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #000000;
  margin-top: 205px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  color: #ffc000;
  height: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #FFFFCC 0%, #FFCC33 100%);
}
.navbar-nav>li {
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}
.nav {
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.navbar {
  min-height: 10px;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav > li:last-of-type {
  border-right: none;
}
.navbar-nav {
  width: 100%;
}
.fon {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  padding-top: -450px;
}
body {
  background: url(images/44.jpg) no-repeat center top #edeef0;
  background-size: 100%;
}
#logo {
  width: 130px;
  height: 77px;
}
#contacts {
  margin-left: 60%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
      <div id="logo">
        <a href="index.html">
          <img src="images/primerlogo.png" alt="" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
      <div id="contacts">
        <span style="font-size: 16px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>E-mail:
        <p>
          <span style="font-size: 16px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span>Телефон: +7-962-702-3737
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="index.html">Главная</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="demo.html">Другой </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="catalog.html">Раздел 3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="contact.html">Контакты</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navmenu navmenu-default" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav navmenu-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Пункт 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

может быть так ?

```css
html,
body {
  height: 4000px;
}
.container {
  width: 95% !important;
  margin: auto;
}
.blog-sidebar {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  width: 22%;
  font-size: 12px!important;
  background: url(http://cherrypapa.com/userfiles/lapsha.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.blog-sidebar li:hover a {
  color: #111;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
          </li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="active"><a href="">Default <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Punkt1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Punkt2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 blog-sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-module sidebar-module-inset">
      <p>Etiam porta <em>sem malesuada magna</em> mollis euismod. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-module">
      <h4>Archives</h4>
      <ol class="list-unstyled">
        <li><a href="#">March 2014</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">February 2014</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">January 2014</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">December 2013</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">November 2013</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">October 2013</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">September 2013</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">August 2013</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">July 2013</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">June 2013</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">May 2013</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">April 2013</a>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-module">
      <h4>Elsewhere</h4>
      <ol class="list-unstyled">
        <li><a href="#">GitHub</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Twitter</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Facebook</a>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

ни когда с bootstrap не работал